# Separate a string with different delimiters in python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I came across a csv file which made me wonder what should be the correct processes to get the info out of it. I want to read each line and then each row in variables lastname, firstname and department but,

structure of the csv file is like this

```
lastname, firstname (department)
```

lets say we have a name Jean-Claude Van Damme

```
Van Damme, Jean-Claude (Karate-Master)
```

what would be the best way to separate such string and store in variables lastname, firstname and the department?

```
import csv
import string
import re

file = open('path/testing_delimiters.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader:
    data = map(string.strip, row)
print data
# output so far
# ['Van Damme', 'Jean-Claude (Karate-Master)']
```

task is to separate Jean-Claude and (Karate-Master)

```
# expected output
# ['Van Damme', 'Jean-Claude', 'Karate-Master']
```

Comment: What you have there is *not* a CSV file.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Seems to call for `re.split()`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: There's no python in the question.

Comment: You wrote as a comment that your file has 38 columns. So please show them and show what you tried and what your problem was.

Comment: i edited what is the expected output and I apologize I cant show the data because it is confidential

Comment: @jorzylicious: We don't care about the data, we care about the data structure. Replace every name with `Donald Duck` if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Pandas** library:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv',sep=',|\(',engine='python',header=None)
```

Use two separators `,` andd `(`
Then you can strip `)`

```
df[2]=df[2].str.strip(')')
```

`[2]` in this case is column number.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions and capturing groups:

```
import re
s = 'Van Damme, Jean-Claude (Karate-Master)'
m = re.match(r'([^,]*),\s+([^,]+)\s+\(([^\(\)]*)\)', s)
lastname, firstname, department = m.groups()
# [^,]*   any non-comma, zero or more
# [^\(\)]*   any non-(), zero or more
# \s+   any whitespace char, one or more
# (...) capturing group
# \( \) match parenthesees, escaped because of special meaning
```

Comment: @PeterWood Which hyphens?

Comment: Does `Jean-Claude` have to have a hyphen, or can it have a space? Same with `Karate-Master`.

Comment: @PeterWood: The names can have any character expect a comma or a paren.

Comment: @PeterWood Updated it so that the names can contain any non-comma and the departmetn any non-parentheses.

Comment: OP's file has 38 columns. This approach won't work well if you want to write a complete regex.

Answer (score -1):

if it's from a csv file, then I think you can import csv [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Then you can iterate it row by row and each row you need to split it by comma. On last name you can search word between the bracket using regex `\((.*?)\)`. at last you need to remove the bracket.